# Is it permitted to daven without shoes?

Tags: tefilla

Is it permitted to daven without shoes when in places where shoes can't be worn for non-Jewish reasons? For example, when using prayer rooms in airports that require shoes to be taken off to keep the floors clean for adherents of other faiths that prostrate.

I don't have a source for wearing shoes other than being taught to always wear shoes (and dress respectfully as if for a king) when davening.

If minhag is relevant, I'm Ashkenazi.

Comment: וַיֹּאמֶר, אַל-תִּקְרַב הֲלֹם; שַׁל-נְעָלֶיךָ, מֵעַל רַגְלֶיךָ--כִּי הַמָּקוֹם אֲשֶׁר אַתָּה עוֹמֵד עָלָיו, אַדְמַת-קֹדֶשׁ הוּא. - שמות פרק ג פסוק ה

Comment: Someone told me that there is a synagogue in Gerba,  a very old synagogue,  in which people take off shoes before entering.